# Change vs code targeted compiler

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, settings

I wonder if someone knows how to change TypeScript's compiler option to something newer within vscode itself in either a global or workspace settings or settings.json

I'm currently dealing with this problem:

```
Property 'values' does not exist on type 'Object'.
Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib`
compiler option to 'es2017' or later.ts(2550)
```

I'm using TypeScript only for it's IDE + JSDoc (meaning I don't write in typescript's syntax) So I don't want to have a tsconfig.json or typescript stuff within my project. I'm writing TS friendly code doe but i don't like compilers that much so I'm using the implicitProjectConfig.checkJs...

I did find out that i could write `/// <reference lib="es2020" />` in the top of the file, but i do not wish to do this kind of thing for every file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is called: **JS/TS › Implicit Project Config: Target**

```
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.target": "ES2017"
```